# TypeScript type cast

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have an object, and I need to add some extra properties to it in some cases.

```js
interface Item {
    name: string
}

function addProp(obj: Item) {
    type WithFoo = Item & { foo?: string; }

    // The following does NOT work
    obj = obj as WithFoo;

    if (obj.name == 'test') {
        obj.foo = 'hello';
     }
}
```

It seems `obj = obj as AnotherType` does NOT work, but if I assign to another variable, it works, `const anotherObj = obj as AnotherType`.

Is there any way to cast the `type`, **without** introducing another variable?

Here is [online playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=13&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJKQLbIN4ChkHIhwYQBcyAzmFKAOa4C+uuMAriAmMAPYjJwAJoIAKUHgAcAFDwBGAKwroIGAJQ58hMAE8JKAOrAwACwBiPHsgC8aTMgBkOZDAsB+CtVog6AbmTNCZDl5ayCFAUpkQxNzHh9NAmAYZBkFADpiUmsbAHJIahz1PEDA4LSXS1zjCAAbGp4c+JLmZlwgA)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**1.) Why does `obj = obj as WithFoo` not work? Is there any way to cast the type, without introducing another variable?**

First of all the `obj` function parameter variable is declared with an `Item` type, so TS does not know that `obj` contains the type `{ foo?: string}`. Your second chance would be the compiler's [control flow analysis](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/8010) for assignments, which in this case cannot narrow the `obj` type to `WithFoo`, as `obj` does not have a union type:

> An assignment (including an initializer in a declaration) of a value of type S to a variable of type T changes the type of that variable to T narrowed by S in the code path that follows the assignment.
>
> The type T narrowed by S is computed as follows:
>
> If T is not a union type, the result is T.
> If T is a union type, the result is the union of each constituent type in T to which S is assignable.

That is the reason, why you get the error `Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'Item'` in the example. Instead the [following code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=10&ssc=2&pln=5&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJKQLbIN4ChkHIhwYQBcyAzmFKAOa4C+uuYAngA4oDqwYAFgDEA9sOQBeHMhiiA-BWq0QdANzJmuGAFcQCMMGEhkcACYmAClGEcAFMIBGAKwroIWAD7JeAkcICUOPiEDo4SyCHGlF58QqIqQQQhAHQyYpIA5PwQADbZwunxGkA) would properly narrow and compile:

```
type WithFoo = { foo?: string; }

function addProp(obj: Item | WithFoo) {
    obj = obj as WithFoo;
    obj.foo = 'hello';
}
```

If you don't want to do re-assignments or introduce another variable, `foo` property can be accessed with an inline [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions), which in general is usable on all [JavaScript expressions](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#416-type-assertions):

```
(obj as WithFoo).foo = 'hello';
```

Having said that, a more safe way is probably to assume `obj` to be a union type `Item | WithFoo` and use [type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types) instead of a hard cast (see @Maciej Sikora's answer).

**2.) Why does `const anotherObj = obj as AnotherType` work?**

When you declare a new variable like `const anotherObj = obj as AnotherType`, the compiler automatically infers the type of variable `anotherObj` to `AnotherType`. TS does additional checks to make sure, `AnotherType` is compatible to `typeof obj`. E.g. [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJKQLbIN4ChkHIhwYQBcyAzmFKAOa4C+uuYAngA4oDqwYAFgDEA9sOQBeHMhiiA-BWq0QdANzJmuGAFcQCMMGEhkcACYmAClGEcAFMIBGAKwroIGAJQ58hBIerGQYQFoAHknCWQHR2NKKhp6ZAB6RORoKyhkGxCAaXdvAmTkADoSphYWIA) wouldn't compile:

```
function addProp(obj: Item) {
    const anotherObj = obj as string // error (OK)
    // ...
}
```

**3.) Can a variable's type be changed after its declaration?**

Nope, `let` and `const` variables [cannot be redeclared](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/904) ([`var`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#52-variable-statements) with same type, but not important here), which implies, the declared variable types also cannot be changed. The variables could be narrowed via control flow analysis though, see 1.).

Comment: So, we can **NOT** change a variable's `type` after it's declaration? In my case, the `type` of `obj` will be `Item` forever, I can't change its `type` to another, even to a compatible `type`? see this [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJKQLbIN4ChkHIhwYQBcyAzmFKAOa4C+uuYAngA4oDqwYAFgDEA9sOQBeNJmQAyHMhiiA-BWq0QdANzJmuGAFcQCMMGEhkcACaWAClGEcAFMIBGAKwroIWAD7JeAiLCAJQ4+ISubhLIkRaU-nxCoprhBMAwyM7uAHTEpBKSAOSQ1IWheISVMTmKYkX8EAA2jcKFKVXMjEA)

Comment: In case 1, if I change type `WithFoo` to this `type WithFoo = { foo?: string; name: string; }`, the cast will fail. see [this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=5&ssc=47&pln=5&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJKQLbIN4ChkHIhwYQBcyAzmFKAOa4C+uuYAngA4oDqwYAFgDEA9sOQBeHMhiiA-BWq0QdANxES5KjXprmuGAFcQCMMGEhkcACZWAClGEcAFMIBGAKwroIWAD7JeARFhAEocfEI3dwlkKMtKAL4hURUIgiiAOhkxSQByfggAG0LhXNS9FlwgA)

Comment: Have a look at the above quotation again. In your playground, after the cast the type of variable `obj` becomes the union of each constituent type in `Item | WithFoo` to which `WithFoo` is assignable. `WithFoo` is assignable to both `Item` and `WithFoo` in your last example, so the resulting type is `Item | WithFoo` again. And TS complains, because `foo` property is not in all constituents of the union (it could be `Item`, then you can't use `foo`).

Answer (score 5):

### 1. Union type approach

What I think you want to do, is to determine some property relations. As it is wrong to just get different type and cast it as it would be another one. I think your `Item` type can have some additional properties in some circumstances, and that we should model in the type definition!

Lets start from proper typing:

```
type ItemNoFoo = { name: string };
type ItemWithFoo = ItemNoFoo & {foo: string}
type Item = ItemNoFoo | ItemWithFoo;
```

I created Item as a union of `ItemNoFoo` and `ItemWithFoo`. Thanks that we can define two different states of our object.

Now I will create a function, guard function which will check if we are `ItemNoFoo` or `ItemWithFoo` states.

```
const hasFoo = (item: Item): item is ItemWithFoo => item.name === 'test';
```

Ok great so we can now ask if `Item` has property foo or not in scope of one type ( as our type is just a union of two other types ).

The final code:

```
type ItemNoFoo = { name: string };
type ItemWithFoo = ItemNoFoo & {foo: string}
type Item = ItemNoFoo | ItemWithFoo;

const hasFoo = (item: Item): item is ItemWithFoo => item.name === 'test';

function addProp(obj: Item) {
    if (hasFoo(obj)) {
        obj.foo = 'hello'; // in if block obj is inferenced as ItemWithFoo!
     }
}
```

Some more info about this approach you can find here - [Sum types](https://dev.to/macsikora/more-accurate-the-type-better-the-code-202l)

---

### 2. Function as data transformer

If it happens that our function needs to create a new structure, so is like a - data creator, or data transformer, then we should look on it as `in -> out` pipe. In types, **in** is `ItemNoFoo` and **out** type is `ItemWithFoo` | `ItemWithFoo` ( types definitions in point 1 ).

```
function transform(obj: ItemNoFoo): Item {
    if (obj.name === 'test') {
        return {
          ...obj,
          foo: 'hello'
        } // here we create new value with new type
     } else {
       return obj;
     }
}
```

As you can see still union type `Item` is handy as this function returns or unchanged `ItemNoFoo` type instance or `ItemWithFoo`.

Lets check the using of it:

```
function f(item: ItemNoFoo) {
  const finalItem = transform(item); // type of finalItem is ItemWithFoo | ItemNoFoo
}
```

If further you want to be sure if you deal with one or another, then handy can be `hasFoo` guard function (defined in solution 1) which will determine which of these two types the value is.

Comment: The `Item` comes from a **backend REST API**, and in the original data, `foo` does **NOT** exist. But I need to add the `foo` property in some circumstances. So, I don't want to change the **return type** of my API request, just to add the `foo` property in my handle function. Anyway, I am wondering can we change some variable's `type` after it's declaration. `obj = obj as ItemWithFoo` does **NOT** change the `obj` type, but assigning to another variable works.

Comment: @Jess check then second options which I added

Answer (score 2):

`obj = obj as WithFoo` does not work because the type of `obj` is `Item` and you want to store in it an object of type `WithFoo`.

But you can use another variable of type `WithFoo` and store `obj` in it. Because `obj` is an object, both variables will keep references to the same data:

```
interface Item {
    name: string
}

function addProp(obj: Item) {
    type WithFoo = Item & { foo?: string; }
    const foo = obj as WithFoo;
    if (obj.name == 'test') {
        foo.foo = 'hello';
     }
}

const x1: Item = { name: 'test' }
addProp(x1);
console.log(x1);

const x2: Item = { name: 'not-matching' }
addProp(x2);
console.log(x2);
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/##ZY8xD4IwEIV3fsVNIoMkMkqIm4mbm3MtBWqgR9ozwRB/O16pHdQb79777j16jspJq0daFm1I2UZIBWdSA8wJ8BgxqAM4stq0yStJmoeRpNGAqOuLxXGLt/thNWQfBzESrpq6EyJUgbWBGRrEYySV8Fq1Eo0jf2Ehg0C46CzXu27AP8h9CqgqSEk5SuMnP@zNgz/tVN9jGozM57ABP@1DQNbMnz6Bw6LYYtpn5SrHXuU9tmERAcU/wCDtBkGy4zZfoOIX5BfL8gY) online.

Comment: I don't understand why `obj = obj as WithFoo` can't change `type` of `obj`. Or can we change an exsiting variable's type in TypeScript?

Comment: The type of variables cannot change. `obj as WithFoo` does not change the type of `obj` or of the object stored in `obj`. It just tells the compiler: *"trust me that the object stored in `obj` follows the interface of `WithFoo`"*. It is not a type cast; neither TypeScript nor Javascript support type casts.

Comment: **"The type of variables cannot change"** I couldn't find any related info in TS docs, though it seems reasonable to me.