# TypeScript Union type assertion or Casting

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

how does TypeScript handle `Union` type assertion or casting?

I've two demo, first works but second fails.

The following works, or you can review the [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=13&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJKQLbIN4ChkHIhwYQBcyAzmFKAOa4C+uuoksiKA6sGABYAxAPZCc+QjBEB+CtVog6AbiYsYAVxAIwwISGRwAJgYAKUIQAcAFEIBGAKwroIWAD7Ie-YUICUYwsls7ZABeAPt9SndeQRFlf0CAOklRUIByPggAG0yhVOVmIA)

```js
interface Item {
    name: string
}

interface WithFoo {
    foo?: string;
}

function addProp(obj: Item | WithFoo) {
    obj = obj as WithFoo;
    // obj's type cast to WithFoo successfully
    obj.foo = 'hello';
}
```

But, the following one **fails**, [see playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJKQLbIN4ChkHIhwYQBcyAzmFKAOa4C+uuoksiKA6sGABYAxAPZCc+QsVIVqtEHQDc4gjBEB+aTXqLmuGAFcQCMMCEhkcACYWAClCEAHABRCARgCsK6CFgA+yHvzCQgCUYoTIrm7IALwR7uaU-ryCIorhkQB0KqKxAOR8EAA2hUK52rhAA)

```js
interface Item {
    name: string
}

interface WithFoo {
    name: string;
    foo?: string;
}

function addProp(obj: Item | WithFoo) {
    obj = obj as WithFoo;
    // ERROR: Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'Item | WithFoo'.
    // Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'Item'.
    obj.foo = 'hello';
}
```

Why TypeScript handle these two differently?

Comment: See my added comment in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58392378/typescript-type-cast/58393708#58393708), does that help you?

Comment: OK, duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/a/58393708/2583885](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58393708/2583885)

Comment: Interesting, looks like a bug in TS. The wanted behavior is by using `(obj as WithFoo).foo = 'hello'`. The assignment you are doing  is compiled to `obj = obj`, so it does nothing but it goes to the runtime. I think you should avoid this not needed assignment.