# how can I change entity type in nestjs with typeorm

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I'm using `typeorm` and `nestjs` on my project.

I have a project with multiple actions in one service.

```js
let aorB: A | B;

if(checkpoint === 'A') { 
    //A point
    aorB = await this.Arepository.findOne();
}else{
    //B point
    aorB = await this.Brepository.findOne();
}

const ab = aorB.onlyAColumn; //error
```

I used the code above, `aorB` would not be changed to type `A` in A Point.

I want the type to change at each point.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use (aorB as A).onlyAColumn. Or probably these answer might help you [TypeScript type cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58392378/typescript-type-cast)